# Redirect the url in asp.net site

Tags: asp.net, iis

I had hosted the sites using the iis 10 with application on the site like below structure:
[image]

Mysite staging Physical Path is D:\inetpub\MysiteStaging
mysitestaging application physical path is D:\inetpub\MysiteStaging\staging

https://www.mysitestaging.com/mysitestaging/Login/Login.aspx is working fine. I need to redirect to this url https://www.mysitestaging.com/mysitestaging/Login/Login.aspx when users type https://www.mysitestaging.com or any text in between the domain name https://www.mysitestaging.com and  /Login/Login.aspx like this https://www.mysitestaging.com/anytext/Login/Login.aspx. Currently I am getting the 404 resource cannot be found.
Any help is really appreciated.
Thanks
Sabbu

Comment: Use the IIS URL Rewriter extension (which can also do redirects and request-proxying in addition to request rewriting): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: @Dai I try to redirect as suggested using URL Rewrite but still the same issue. I am not able to past the screen shot of rules I added here.

Comment: Post your `<rewrite>` element from your `web.config` and show us the HTTP redirects from your browser's devtools' Network tab.

Comment: <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect to Login" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="https://mysitestaging.com*" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url=""https://mysitestaging.com/mysitestaging/Login/Login.aspx" redirectType="Found" />
                </rule>
            </rules>

Comment: Your `<match>` pattern is incorrect: the `<match url=""` attribute is for the request path, not the hostname/authority: that goes in the `<conditions>` element. This is all covered in the documentation and reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference

Comment: Next time edit the question to include new information so that you can well format it. Never do that in comments. Besides, learn and avoid common rewrite mistakes, https://halfblood.pro/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this rule:

```
<rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(^$|(.*)/Login/Login.aspx)$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/mysitestaging/Login/Login.aspx" />
</rule>
```